# Do you need to share source code of the theme when using inside web application that use AGPL?

Tags: agpl-3.0

If I have an AGPL web application that supports themes for customization and someone uses the application with a given theme on the server. Does the theme need to have the same AGPL license?

What will hypothetically happen if WordPress was AGPL?

Comment: What kind of interface exists between the AGPL software and the theme? Is the theme itself a software, or is it configuration data for the software?

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT Theme is in EJS (template language), HTML, and CSS. I'm not sure if this is software or not. For me it is, that's why I'm asking this question.